# Are any of Romero's "Dead" films connected other than these two?

Tags: zombie, romero, night-of-the-living-dead

[Night of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead) (1968), [Dawn of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Dead) (1978), [Day of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dead_%281985_film%29) (1985), and [Land of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Dead) (2005), all seem to be products of their time, tackling relevant social issues within the confines of the zombie subset of the horror genre. Yet they don't actually seem to connect in any substantial way, ie: other than the director ([George A. Romero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_A._Romero)), the zombie subject matter, and title similarities of what is usually referred to as the [Dead Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead_%28film_series%29) (even though the wikilink refers to the longer title).

Then comes [Diary of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary_of_the_Dead) (2007) and [Survival of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_of_the_Dead) (2008) with an obvious overlap of characters and timelines. *Diary* also includes a reference to *Night*. According the Wikipedia page:

> The film is the fifth film in Romero's Dead series and there are some notable references to earlier Romero films, as when the news track from 1968's Night of the Living Dead is used in the scene where the cast is in Ben's garage; but the film is not a direct sequel to any of Romero's films: the film is "a rejigging of the myth" according to Romero, and is meant as a side story during the same timeframe as Night of the Living Dead.

Other than something as subtle as a newscast, was there any other attempt to connect the earlier films, in-universe?

Comment: Romero rarely has enough directorial skill to connect his films in a meaningful way, but they are a single series.

Comment: I mentioned they are a series, but if he didn't mean to connect them other than being in the same universe (until 2008), how is that a failure of his directorial skills?

Comment: I've read that Romero was trying to build a "dead series" shared universe, but the producers of his films (Rubinstein in particular, if rumors are true) didn't want to dilute their "properties."  Could have been so ahead of its time, if not for greed.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, not really. However, having said that -

---

The police officer played by Joseph Pilato in *Dawn*, is seen by some fandom to be the same character he plays in *Day* - Rhodes.

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088993/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) says this of the theory:

> Although never confirmed, it has been rumored by fans that the
>   character Joe Pilato played in *Dawn of the Dead* is in fact Rhodes as a
>   cop. Fans believe that Rhodes started out as a cop then later joined
>   the army and became Captain. Since no passage of time is given in the
>   dead films it is very possible that years lapsed between dawn and day,
>   and that the Rhodes character could have went from being a cop to an
>   army captain.

I haven't been able to find anything else on it.

This is somewhat tangentially confirmed / homaged in the remakes released in the 2000s where Ving Rhames played a cop in the *Dawn* remake and the Rhodes character in the *Day* remake.

---

One of the bikers killed in *Dawn*, played by Tom Savini, shows up in *Land* as a zombie. Whether this is the same character is debatable as he does a lot of horror work. (He was also in the *Dawn* remake).

Comment: The Savini character in Land was more of in-joke, as he carried a Machete, just like in Dawn. They're old friends and did it as a nod to the fans. I never made that Rhames/Pilato cop/captain connection, though. I wonder if that was by design or just a fortuitous "look at this" thing. Interesting...